# Animation not getting displayed on maui app with SkiaSharp

Tags: c#, xaml, nuget, maui

i'm just hard coding an animation in maui using SkiaSharp and the animation is not displayed when i run the app. it certainly takes the amount of space that i'm setting but it doesn't display anything.

[csproj file with the references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1XaM.png)

XAML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="WeatherApplication.MainPage"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:WeatherApplication.Model"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:WeatherApplication.ViewModel"
             xmlns:skia="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Extended.UI.Controls;assembly=SkiaSharp.Extended.UI"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:YourCurrentLocationForecast"
             Title="{Binding Title}">

   
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <skia:SKLottieView Source="Resources/Raw/sunny.json" 
                        RepeatCount="-1" HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="100" />
        <Button BackgroundColor="Yellow"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>


</ContentPage>
```

the mauiprogram.cs code with the UseSkiaSharp() method

```
using SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Controls.Hosting;

namespace WeatherApplication;

public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>().UseSkiaSharp()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConnectivity>(Connectivity.Current);
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IGeolocation>(Geolocation.Default);
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMap>(Map.Default);
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<YourCurrentLocationForecast>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherService>();

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

no matter what version i use, it still doesn't display anything. i tried with cli from nuget site, also tried in vs for mac just like here: https://cedricgabrang.medium.com/implementing-lottie-animations-in-your-net-maui-application-62bd484af651

Comment: Just use “sunny.json” as the source

Comment: i tried every possible way of introducing the path to the source. the thing is, it takes up the space required in the app, but it doesn't display it. it's remains an empty space.

Comment: May I ask what .Net version and platform you are targeting?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT dotnet version: 8.0.201 and 
Microsoft.Maui.Controls                         8.0.6          
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility  8.0.6

Comment: And what platform, Android, iOS or Windows?

Comment: tried both on Android and iOS but still nothing

Comment: First I agree with Jason that you just have to set ```<skia:SKLottieView Source="sunny.json"```.  And I have also made a demo which works well based on your code but with another json file. So have you tried different json files?

Comment: i got 3 json fiels from lottiefiles but none worked, could you provide me with your json so i could try on my machine?

Comment: You may also refer to the good [lottie animation tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o5X5yXdWpuc) by Gerald Versluis and its [sample project](https://github.com/jfversluis/MauiLottieAnimationsSample).

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/5idWqyJ it still remains the same. in the stacklayout i placed the animation first and then a yellow button just to demonstrate that it's there but not visible

Comment: Actually I cannot reproduce. I followed the tutorial by Gerald Versluis amd all works well. So have you tried creating a new default project and have another try? And don't forget clean the solution.

Comment: I also notice that you use dependency injection. Right now I am not sure if it relates. Could you please share us the relevant code how you use that, especially for MainPage?

Comment: To be more specific I also post an answer below. May I ask for your patience to check if there is anything I haven't noticed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use .NET8 with SkiaSharp.Extended.UI.Maui(Version="2.0.0-preview.86")

I put the json file in Resource/Raw folder,

[image]

And I set the MainPage,

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App(MainPage mainPage)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(mainPage);
    }
}
```

Of course I register the MainPage in MauiProgram,

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();
```

In MainPage.xaml, I use almost the same code,

```
 <VerticalStackLayout>
    <skia:SKLottieView Source="dotnetbot.json" 
                    RepeatCount="-1" HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="100" />
    <Button BackgroundColor="Yellow"/>
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

---

Target on iPad Pro iOS17.2,

[image]

Comment: oh ,thank you for taking your time to help me, it works now in vs code, but in vs for mac it still doesn't, such a weird behaviour. i'm trying now to bind it to a variable called animationVariable with the observable property annotation from the viewmodel class, but even though the variable has the animation json name assigned to it, it seems it behaves the same as i told you above, not being visible.

Comment: Yes, really weird. You know I create the above demo using VS for Mac. So, update the VS for Mac to see if it works.